# Annotate ggplot bar plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

How can I annotate the following plot? I want to include counts on top of each bar.

```
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))
# Number of cars in each class:
g + geom_bar()
```

I only know how to do it if I do a group by and create a new column 'count' for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count)), nudge_y = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How can I put the labels a little higher?

Comment: Adjust the `nudge_y` however you please @Eisen

Comment: I used the position argument with `position_dodge()` instead. I'm having trouble however with reordering. It seems I can't reorder by stat = 'count'? Do you know how I can get around this?

Comment: Do you have multiple groups at each x position, or are you just reordering the x axis?

Comment: reordering x axis!